# Change AngularJS opening and closing tags

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

I'm trying to change angular opening and closing tags, (for python django jinja, if that matter)
So for example, instead of this

```
<div ng-app="">
    <span>name - type: <input type="text" ng-model="name" /></span>
    <span>name - output: {{name}}</span>
</div>
```

I'll have this

```
<div ng-app="">
    <span>name - type: <input type="text" ng-model="name" /></span>
    <span>name - output: [[name]]</span>
</div>
```

And I've already tried this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

and it doesn't works at all. I also tried to replace each `{{` in the `angularjs.js` file, with `[[`, (and `}}` with `]]`) and it's still doesn't change anything.

And yes, I saw that it's not recommended to do something like this, (because of security reasons) but I still need that.

And i'm also need that in AngularJS, not in python. (to replace the symbols in angular, not in python)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it has to be something like this:

```
angular.module('YourAppName', [], function ($interpolateProvider) {
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');     
});
```

Comment: oh ok.. I had problem with the app name.. It's working now, Thanks!

And by the way, why it's so no secure to change the symbol? How it affects the security of the library? (angularjs)

Comment: Any alteration of the default behavior provides certain risk of being in conflict with other similar tagging, say vue.js has {{}} and django templates have {{}}, so if at some point two of the frameworks will have [[]] then change is necessary again.

Comment: oh ok.. and how can I make it "global" - not just for the specific app? (not just for "YourAppName", in your example)